# iPhone Admob UITableView troubles

Tags: iphone, admob

I am sure this is a simple fix, but I can't seem to find it.  I have a table view that currently works just fine, set up as:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}


NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
cell.textLabel.text = [creedsList objectAtIndex:row];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[creedsImages objectAtIndex:row]];

return cell;
```

The Admob SDK says to add this line:

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:[AdMobView requestAdWithDelegate:self]];
```

But then it populates EVERY cell with ads.  Any thoughts?

EDIT:
I am using this code to populate:

```
NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
cell.textLabel.text = [creedsList objectAtIndex:row];
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to do that on only the particular rows you want the ads to show up in.

So if you wanted to show up only on the first row, you could do something like

```
static int adTag = 999; // Used for identifying whether cell already contains ad
UIView * adView = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:adTag];

if(row == 0 && !adView)
{   
    adView = [AdMobView requestAdWithDelegate:self];
    adView.tag = adTag;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:adView];    
}
else if(row != 0 && adView)
{
    // Must remove since cells are reused.
    [adView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: This actually causes some weird behavior.  It covers up my first object and the last object.  Then, when I scroll, it starts popping random ads in random cells.

Comment: @Rob: You need to appropriately remove the view from the cells you don't want them in. Cells are reused, so you need to check and remove the ads if they're not in the particular row you want them in. As it is, it's pretty unclear what you're intending to do with the ads within the table. If you're adding them directly to the cells, then the view will cover that cell. If you could be more specific with your needs, I can get a better idea on what answer to give.

Comment: I am currently populating the cells with an NSArray that has 11 objects.  I would like the ad to populate the first and only the first cell.  I have edited my post to show how how it is being populated.

Comment: @Rob: See edited version. Forgot to tag the adviews correctly. As for the issue of not having it cover up the first item, you'll need to increase the number of rows by one and offset the rows correctly to accomodate for the extra adview cell.

Comment: @David:Still not working.It is still populating cells at the bottom of the UITableView and then random ads appear when I scroll.  I am also getting a yellow flag in the code on the [adView removeFromSuperView] line that says, "UIView may not respond to -removeFromSuperView.

Comment: @Rob: It's a typo. The correct spelling is removeFromSuperview, with lowercase v.

Comment: @David: Wow, I really appreciate all of your help, and I wish I could say that that was the problem - but the behavior is still erratic.  I changed it to Superview instead of SuperView, but I am still getting the same behavior.

Comment: @Rob: Blah, final edit: [cell viewWithTag:adTag]; should be [cell.content viewWithTag:adTag]; That's what I get for not vetting my own code.